# Can I save my weighted companion cube in room 17?

Tags: portal

At the end of room 17 you are asked to toss your cube into the fire before it will let you complete the level.

Without using cheats, is there a way to save it?

Comment: Of *course* there's a way to save it. You didn't actually incinerate your own companion cube, did you? You monster.

Comment: All Aperture technologies remain safely operational up to 4000 degrees Kelvin.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

There is indeed a way to save your loyal Companion Cube.

You merely need to take advantage of two deficiencies in Aperture Science's Test Chambers.  One flaw in Test Chamber 16 lets you push a Weighted Storage Cube through the Material Emancipation Grill and take it up in the elevator to Test Chamber 17. In that chamber, another defect allows you to use the lesser cube to obtain a second Companion Cube. You can then euthanize it instead of your own faithful companion, thereby tricking the Emergency Intelligence Incinerator and shattering another test subject's dreams for the future.

This YouTube video has the details:

Comment: "deficiencies" - erm, you mean bugs?

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - this looks intended, not a bug. Well, at least intended by Valve, if not by Aperture Science.

Comment: @ripper234: I'm not sure if I would consider "pushing a cube at an awkward angle *through a wall edge* into a portal" can be considered *not* a bug. I don't know what's going in that swap-maneuver, though, but it also looks like a bug in a trigger of some sort.

Answer (score 43):

No, I'm afraid not. There's no way to take the companion cube outside this testing chamber, as the door will not open until you've dropped it in the incinerator.

Any stories you may hear about methods of circumventing this process are merely the fictions of devious minds, designed solely for the purpose of instilling false hope. It'll be better for everyone once you accept the inevitability of your hideous betrayal.

The video is propaganda advanced by dangerously bad test-subjects. It is clearly a violation of both the constraints and the intent of the test to employ exploits of this sort, and is frankly bad science.

Comment: So you say @Matthew's video is a fake?

Comment: @ripper234 I'm saying Matthew's video is _propaganda_ advanced by dangerously bad test-subjects. It is clearly a violation of both the constraints and the intent of the test to employ exploits of this sort, and is frankly bad science.

Comment: GLaDOS has just read this in my head...

Answer (score 1):

The video glitch **does** work **but**

It will get destroyed by the blue wall thingy...

So you don't need to destroy the cube.. But you can't bring it past test room 17....

I managed to do the first part of the glitch just now... But found out that I couldn't bring it past that room...

So sad...

Answer (score -1):

Technically, the Source Engine says the following technique isn't a cheat, but there are uses for it that may make some people say it *is* a cheat when, to be honest, Valve's C++ code insists it isn't.

So, go through all the stuff in Test Chamber 17, toss your friend into the Incinerator, and go past the Emancipation Grill.

**BUT DON'T GET IN THE ELEVATOR YET!!!**

Instead, open up the game's settings page and enable the "Developer's Console". Then, exit out of the pause menu, aim your crosshairs at a spot on the floor a little bit away from you, and hit the **`** key (if you've left all the control settings at default, then this should be the key for opening the developer's console) to open the Developer's Console. Then, type in the following command:

ent_create_portal_companion_cube

Then, exit out of the Developer's console in the same fashion as you would exit the pause menu. Do it right and you'll find your faithful friend sitting there on the floor in front of you, happily and ever-so-patiently waiting for you to pick him up and cuddle!

The game lets you take any object/NPC with you in the elevator and into the next chamber easily. Without the Emancipation Grill at the end of every chamber, there wouldn't really be anything stopping you from, saaaaaay, taking your faithful friend with you into the elevator.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Using the console doesn't really count as a way to solve the problem.